# How to echo 1st and 15th of the month in php

Tags: php, date

I need to echo the 1st and 15th of every month Jan-Dec in PHP. I know how to add days using

```
$date1 = $_POST['previous_pay_date'];
  $date2 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date1 . " + 7 day"));
  $date3 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date2 . " + 7 day"));
  $date4 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date3 . " + 7 day"));

  $date1 = $_POST['previous_pay_date'];
  $date2 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date1 . " + 14 day"));
  $date3 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date2 . " + 14 day"));
  $date4 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date3 . " + 14 day"));

  $date1 = $_POST['previous_pay_date'];
  $date2 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date1 . " + 1 month"));
  $date3 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date2 . " + 1 month"));
  $date4 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date3 . " + 1 month"));
  $date5 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date4 . " + 1 month"));
```

But now I need just the 1st and 15th of the month

Comment: String concat?  [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime)?  You should probably [refamiliarize yourself with the date & time functions](http://php.net/ref.datetime).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you give an example of what the output has to be?

Comment: $date1 = Nov 15, 2012 // previous date so then the next date would be $date2 = Dec 1st, then $date3 = Dec 15th, then $date4 = Jan 1st. Basically a pay period in which occurs on the 1st and 15th

Answer (score 1):

My solution, with DateTime objects: Seems much simpler, doesn't it?

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$date = new DateTime("2012-01-01");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d"), PHP_EOL;
$date->modify("+14 days");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d"), PHP_EOL;

while ($date->format("Y") != "2013") {
    $date->modify("first day of next month");
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d"), PHP_EOL;
    $date->modify("+14 days");
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d"), PHP_EOL;
}
```