# Inserting New year To Calendar for Bi-Monthly schedule

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to echo 1st and 15th of the month in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571203/how-to-echo-1st-and-15th-of-the-month-in-php)

Able to print out Dec 1, 2012 & Dec 15, 2012, but cannot get it to proceed past that point to Jan 1, 2013 7 Jan 15 2013 and so on:

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
 date('M 1, Y', strtotime($i . "/1/" . date("Y")));
 date('M 15, Y', strtotime($i . "/15/" . date("Y")));
}
```

Comment: If you had used my solution on your previous question, using `DateTime` objects, and not this monstrosity, it would have been easier for you :)

Answer (score 0):

date("Y") - Would output current year, that is why it is not going past Jan 1, 2012.

So one of the options would be

```
$currentYear = date('Y');
for ($year = $currentYear; $year < $currentYear + 3; $year++)
{
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
       date('M 1, Y', strtotime($i . "/1/" . $year));
       date('M 15, Y', strtotime($i . "/15/" . $year));
    }     
}
```

This will go through 2012, 2013, 2014.